# Azure-Add Certificate to CloudService

Tags: azure, xmlhttprequest, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I want to Add service certificate to my CloudService of Azure via REST API. Currently I have this:

heres my Request Body: based on this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460817.aspx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CertificateFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
<Data>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</Data>
  <CertificateFormat>cer</CertificateFormat>
</CertificateFile>
```

but it gives me error:*The specified certificate's file format is invalid. The certificate file must be a Base64-encoded .pfx file.*

Im certain about the certificate in Base64. What I did to get this is I used and upload manually the same My.cer file to different cloudservice and use [List Service Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460788.aspx) to view its Base64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer to your problem is that **`Service Management API documentation is screwed up`**. Essentially the API does not care of `CertificateFormat` node and **you have to always pass `pfx` there**. You would also need to provide `Password` node as well with no value there because you're uploading a `cer` file. So based on all of this, please try the following as your request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CertificateFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
<Data>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</Data>
  <CertificateFormat>pfx</CertificateFormat>
  <Password></Password>
</CertificateFile>
```

Many thanks to [`@AzureCoder`](https://twitter.com/azurecoder) from [`http://elastacloud.com/`](http://elastacloud.com/) for putting me in the right direction.